# What is the role of the curly brace in this case in Perl?

Tags: perl, curly-braces

The following *print* statements are valid in accessing the 1st element of the array reference

```
my $aref = [6, 7, 8];
print $aref->[0];
print $$aref[0];
print ${$aref}[0];
```

What is the reason for allowing/using the curly brace in the 3rd print? Does it work by design or by chance?

Comment: http://perlmonks.org/?node=References+quick+reference

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is that the expression inside the braces can be arbitrarily complex. Imagine, for example, that you had an object with a method that returned a list of array references - and that you wanted to use the second reference in that list. Then you could use the following code:

```
print ${ ($obj->array_generator)[1] }[0];
```

Inside the braces you can use any expression that returns an array reference. It is only in the simple case (where the expression is a simple scalar variable) that you can omit the braces.

Of course, using this syntax to look up elements in the referenced array is rarely a good idea - I'd always recommend the arrow syntax instead.

```
print +($obj->array_generator)[1]->[0];
```

**Update:** Something I forgot to mention originally - the expression has to be enclosed in braces as it is a block of code that returns an array reference. It doesn't have to be a single expression. You could (but probably shouldn't!) write code like this:

```
print ${
  my @arefs = $object->array_generator;
  my $aref = $arefs[1];
  $aref;
}[0];
```

Comment: I feel like using curly brace to achieve the above is patchy; I think it'd be more "natural" to use parenthesis instead, as in some other languages; but that is not possible because $( is already a built-in var. In your example above of "print +(...", would replacing it with "print +{..." still work? I find my head unnecessarily spinning to have to think thru which form of "grouping" (to give precedence) (parenthesis or curly brace) is valid.

Comment: It has to be braces as it is literally a block of code. You can't replace `+(` with `+{` as that's a list slice and lists are constructed with `( ... )`.

Comment: Your reference of the term "block of code" helps remove my confusion. I'd been thinking of the curly braces in terms of "grouping", while it should be viewed as a "block" construct.

Answer (score 2):

`$BLOCK[EXPR]` allowed `${ get_ref() }[0]` before you could do `get_ref()->[0]`.

---

I think the (preferred) arrow notation syntax (`$EXPR->[EXPR]`) is newer than the inline syntax. The inline syntax for array element dereference is the following:

```
$BLOCK[EXPR]
```

This allows

```
${ get_ref() }[0]   # And even more complex blocks, including one with multiple statements.
```

However, for convenience,

```
${ $ref }[EXPR]     # BLOCK contains a simple scalar
```

can be shortened to

```
$$ref[EXPR]
```

See [Dereferencing Syntax](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=977408).